# Why is my slideshow not looped

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow

For some reason my slideshow is not looped. The whole website is fairly old and running on Joomla, I've been asked to transform a Flash-based slideshow into a jQuery one.

http://www.colours.ltd.uk/lazzari/index2.php

With help of one of you I managed to get the slideshow running but now for some reason, after it goes through all of them it's not looped, it stops on a white screen. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
//Slideshow
jQuery(function() {
        jQuery("#slideshow1 > li:gt(0)").hide();

 setInterval(function() { 
          jQuery('#slideshow1 > li:first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow1');
        },  6000);  
        });
```

I noticed that for some reason "opacity: 0;" stays, while on one of my other sites it disappears asap, allowing the loop to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, there was a huge conflict between the jQuery and Prototype libraries. I updated prototype to the latest version and it seems to be working now, hopefully I didn't break anything.

Comment: Accept this answer if it is the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this with the `repeat()` function

```
$('#slideshow img').hide().repeat().each($).fadeIn(1000).wait(6000).fadeOut(1000)​;
```

********** UPDATE **********

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gmaniac/9h5Let17/

Comment: Sorry, that didn't help at all :/

Comment: didn't see you posted a new answer, glad you got it figured out.